# Why doesn't Google Colaboratory give an output for kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Label (text="tushar")

if __name__=="__main__":
  MyApp().run
```

I was running this simple code on Google Colaboratory. But I didn't get any output. The reason for using Google Colaboratory is that my mobile application must support TensorFlow which is not supported on my PC. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's unlikely that kivy will work on colab.

Answer (score 0):

For most UIs (User Interfaces) you need to a render (Kivy works with OpenGL). This render is not available yet in Colab.